# Extracting substring from BLOB converted in VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, casting, substring, blob, varchar2

I have this flexible search in Oracle:

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_targetCarts, 4000,1)) 
from {OrderProposal}
```

and the result is this:

> �srjava.util.ArrayListx��a�Isizexpwt 0000031072x
>
> �srjava.util.ArrayListx��a�Isizexpwt 0000031087x
>
> �srjava.util.ArrayListx��a�Isizexpwt 0000032360x
>
> �srjava.util.ArrayListx��a�Isizexpwt 0000040099x
>
> �srjava.util.ArrayListx��a�Isizexpwt 0000040100x

I would now extract the code that is in there. The code is the number that begin with '00000' and end before the 'x' character.

There is a possible way to do this?

Comment: Use substr and from first 0 to the end of the string

Comment: Ok I found the solution: 
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_targetCarts, 11,60)) from {OrderProposal}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with:

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_targetCarts, 11,60)) 
from {OrderProposal}
```

In this way I trim the code string to my selection.
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_targetCarts, 4000,1)),'[[:alpha:]]')
  from {OrderProposal}
```

Comment: So and so, there are still some strange characters. I found the solution with select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_targetCarts, 11,60)) proposal from {OrderProposal}